# Default image in magento extension

Tags: image, module

I'm trying to develop a module to show a list of categories' name and image, my controller send an array contains names and images url to my block, i want to show a default image if no image assign to any category:

-so my questions where is the better place to check if  the image url is null and assign the default image url (in controller or in block).

-my second part of the question where to save this image in media or in skin folder as im planning to use it in defferent themes and i dont want to change the code every time i move it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the category and check for a valid image url

```
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId);
    $_catImgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()
    if (!$_catImgUrl) {
      $_catImgUrl=Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'yourmodule/default-image.png'
    }
```

I would create a media folder for your module and store the images in media/yourmodule.

Comment: i used something similar but i have question if i want to use skin folder how to use the  current url for the theme skin folder from controller

Comment: For the skin url try Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('your folder/yourfile.file')